# limit of $\frac{2xy^3}{7x^2+4y^6}$, different answers.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Good evening, everyone I've tried my possible best to evaluate the limit as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ but Using sage the answer is 0 either ways but one textbook is saying the limit doesn't exist.  Could the 2 answers be correct?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain exactly what you did with Sage, and what you mean by "either ways". I have a feeling the explanation lies there.

Comment: @Xrobot : CAS's make mistakes.  Read the proof in the textbook until you understand it.

Comment: @Eldredge here's what I did in Sage ..`sage: f(x,y)= 2*x*y^3/((7*x^2)+(4*y^6))` `sage: f.limit(x=0)` Sage replies `(x, y) |--> 0` and then I try `sage: f.limit(y=0)` the answer is again `(x, y) |--> 0` showing the limit exists and is `0`. Is there a better way of doing this? I am not an expert in Sage

Comment: As far as I can tell you asked Sage to compute $\lim_{y \to 0} \lim_{x \to 0}$, which is NOT the same as $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}$.

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This limit does not exist.

If you approach $(0,0)$ along the $x$-axis, your expression tends to $0$.

On the other hand, if you approach along the curve $x=y^3$, you get
$$
\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)\\\text{along $x=y^3$}}}\frac{2xy^3}{7x^2+4y^6}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2y^6}{11y^6}=\frac{2}{11}\neq0.
$$

Comment: The textbook wrote exactly the same thing. I just wonder what went wrong with Sage.

Comment: CA packages like Sage and Mathematica sometimes miss limits that vary depending on the path of approach.

Comment: I've got it confirmed by our analysis lecturer here in my school. Grateful to everyone for your contributions.

Answer (score 2):

The Wolfram|Alpha result is indeed a weakness (bug).

In slightly more detail, which I hope I won't have to regret, the underlying problem is in Mathematica's Limit handling of intervals.

ee = (rho*Interval[{-1, 1}])/(rho^2*Interval[{-1, 1}] + 
     Interval[{-1, 1}]);

In[63]:= Limit[ee, rho -> 0]

This incorrectly gives zero when it should return unevaluated.

This is a known bug. What's not known at this point is how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the note was in response to @Brian Rushton. It was too long for a comment. I do not know if it related to the Sage result in terms of the underlying failure. Mathematica is attempting to assess the range of values in a disk as the radius goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Take $y=\sqrt[3]{x}$, then you obtain
$$\frac{2xy^3}{7x^2+4y^6}=\frac 2{11}\neq 0$$.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is the problem is that sage cannot test every approach curve, so it probably tests a small grid of points about the origin. Since the place where the limit is bad is shaoed like a curved cubic, the grid will miss the curve and give the wrong answer.

Note that Wolfram Alpha has the same problem: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+as+x+goes+to++0%2C+y+goes+to+0+of+%5Cfrac%7B2xy%5E3%7D%7B7x%5E2%2B4y%5E6%7D&incCompTime=true

Comment: Worst still it uses Mathematica as one of its algorithms.